# Is there a way to count the number of values in a row that are greater than a "variable" value in Pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, countif

I have two separated DataFrames:

df1:

```
Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5
ID1   2     3      5     0
ID2   7     6     11     5
ID3   9    16     20    12
```

df2:

```
Col1  ColB 
ID1   2   
ID2   7   
ID3   9
```

Is there a way to count how many values in the first row of `df1` are greater than the first value in the column `ColB` in `df2`? I need this counting for each row and to add it at the end of `df1`. So, `df1` can be looked like this:

df1:

```
Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5 COUNT
ID1   2      3      5    0    2
ID2   7      6     11    5    1
ID3   9     16     20   12    3
```

Thank you for any suggestion!

Comment: You can [merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101) and use [df.gt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html#pandas-dataframe-gt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prior assumption is that 'Col1' is the index.
If not, add `.set_index('Col1')` after df1/df2 in the right part of the commands:

You can use the underlying numpy array:

```
df1['COUNT'] = (df1.values>df2.values).sum(axis=1)

# if "Col1" is not index
df1['COUNT'] = (df1.set_index('Col1').values>df2.set_index('Col1').values).sum(axis=1)
```

or:

```
df1['COUNT'] = df1.gt(df2['ColB'].values[:, None]).sum(axis=1)

# if "Col1" is not index
df1['COUNT'] = df1.set_index('Col1').gt(df2['ColB'].values[:, None]).sum(axis=1)
```

output:

```
      Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5  COUNT
Col1                               
ID1      2     3     5     0      2
ID2      7     6    11     5      1
ID3      9    16    20    12      3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('Col1')
df1.assign(COUNT = df1.gt(df2.set_index('Col1').squeeze(),axis=0).sum(axis=1))
```